# Convert <select> to <ul> in Angular transclude

Tags: javascript, css, .net, angularjs

Problem: Front end gets given a select element from a .Net html helper, it requires styling on hover, which doesnt seem possible with a select tags options.

To fix this I decided to try convert `<select>` to `<ul>` on the front end then add the hover css rules to the new li elements

I first clone the element, do the processing on the second element, remove the original and insert the new element.

However when I replace the select with ul and option with li, it doesn't seem to go back to the same format as the original and I get the following which happens at $element.$append($clone);

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement]**

Can anyone help with where I'm going wrong? The original code is generated in this function:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx

```
transclude($scope.$parent, function ($clone, $scope) {
    console.log('original clone', $clone);

    var outer = $clone[1].outerHTML;
    console.log('$clone[1]', outer);


    var selectCode = $clone[1].cloneNode(true);

​
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.appendChild(selectCode);
    selectCode = selectCode.toString().replace(/select/g, 'ul');

​
    delete $clone[1];
    console.log('clone after remove child', $clone);

​
    $clone.splice(1, 1, selectCode)
    console.log('clone after insert child', $clone);
​

    console.log('clone before end', $clone);
    $element.append($clone);
});
```